# Print SQL Result via php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to SUM 2 Columns then subtract the difference. In SQL the following code outputs the correct response.

However i'm not sure how to print it via php...

SQL - Code:

```
SELECT budget_id, SUM( Amount ) - SUM( Expenditure ) AS diff FROM budget
```

This is my php code...

PHP - Code:

```
                    $sql = "SELECT budget_id, SUM( Amount ) - SUM( Expenditure ) AS  diff FROM budget";

                  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

                  print "$".$result;
                  ?>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: You need use $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); echo $dif = $row['diff'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `mysql_fetch_array`

```
$sql = "SELECT budget_id, SUM( Amount ) - SUM( Expenditure ) 
AS  diff FROM budget";
              $result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
              while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
              {
              print_r($result);// to see the contents of the array
              echo $result[budget_id];
              echo $result[diff];
              }
```

**Dont use mysql_*** as they are depracated.

Comment: Thanks all ...

I modified the above and this worked...

    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT budget_id, SUM( Amount ) - SUM( Expenditure ) AS diff FROM budget";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    echo "$".$result[diff];
    }
    ?>

Comment: Thanks Raj, sorry very new to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your help I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The return of mysql_query is a result resource u can iterate over with this bit of code:

```
// fetch each row of the result as an associative array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    print $row['diff'] . "\n";
}
```

But keep in mind that the mysql_* functions in PHP are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and will be remove in a future release. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php).